# Why 'onSnapshot' google firebase is so fast, instantly fired?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I build a simple react app to test google firebase. Anyone have any idea how the `onSnapshot` method works? I mean, it is so fast (like, instantly), even when I change network to slow 3G in devtools, it still fast. I noticed in XHR tab, when the app made request to firebase, request is still pending, but `onSnapshot` already fired and change the state in my react app. I thought it will wait until there's response from firebase, but that's not the case.

```
.firestore()
  .collection("expense")
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const newExpense = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      return {
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      };
    });

    //set state is fired, but request is still pending
    this.setState({expense: newExpense});
  });
```

Did firebase just store the app state somewhere, or just simply read the app state and then update the state (call `onSnapshot`) when making request? If that's the case then you can not handle network error (or you can but that would be weird), because the app state is already changed.

Did firebase update the app state when this function (function below is to add collection to firebase database) called? and didn't even wait until request is success?

```
firebase.firestore().collection("expense").add(value);
```

Comment: might be related to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: Ah, I think that's the answer. I just test locally, and found that the app state will change whether request to firebase is success or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

When you write to Firestore from your application, the Firestore client in that application immediately fires events for the local listeners to that data.

So after your call to `firebase.firestore().collection("expense").add(value)` the Firestore client does:

1. Send the new data off to the server.
2. Calls any local listeners to `/expenses` straight away.

It's the second step here that makes the local chances show up instantly, as it doesn't wait for the server to complete the write operation.

This leads to a possible problem: what happens if the server rejects the write operation (for example because it conflicts with the security rules of your database)? If that happens, a few more steps are taken:

3. The server checks the write against the security rules and rejects it.
4. The client then fires reconciliation events for the local state, so it calls your `onSnapshot` listener again with the document removed.

Because of these extra steps, it is possible to briefly see the new document appear and then be removed, if it violates the security rules of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was curious before because I keep thinking of the possible problem you just said. I am relieved now lol, thanks again, Frank, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, [offline storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, thanks to Aprillion for mentioning [this explanation](http://%20firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

Firebase will cache the data you get, read from that and update the state based on that data while still making network request, that's why it is instantly